# Customized UITableViewCell not works like Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I want create a cell to user put value, so have a label to describe the field and the label (tap gesture) to browser to search a value. The value of  black label can have differents values (1 line, 2 lines...) so this must be dynamic. I tried this:

[image]

The result:

[image]

I want put black label at bottom of wine label.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: And what are the constraints of your two labels?

Comment: set the bottom constraints to use UITableViewAutomatic dimension or provide a specific height of cell